# Screen sharing using webRTC when audio call in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, socket.io, webrtc

I am going to make screen sharing function using webRTC.
My code is working well when video calling
But in audio call status, that is not working.
Here is my code.

This is for create peer Connection and add stream for audio calling

```
const senders = [];
var mediaConstraints = {audio: true, video: false}
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(mediaConstraints)
    .then(function (localStream) {
        localLiveStream = localStream;
        document.getElementById("local_video").srcObject = localLiveStream;
        localLiveStream.getTracks().forEach(track => senders.push(myPeerConnection.addTrack(track, localLiveStream)));
            })
    .catch(handleGetUserMediaError);
```

when screen share field

```
mediaConstraints.video = true;
let displayStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(mediaConstraints)
if (displayStream) {
    document.getElementById("local_video").srcObject = displayStream;
    console.log("senders: ", senders);
    try {
        senders.find(sender => sender.track.kind === 'video').replaceTrack(displayStream.getTracks()[0]);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("Error: ", e)
    }
}
```

In screen sharing status, sender.track.kind is "audio"
So

```
senders.find(sender => sender.track.kind === 'video') = null.
```

As this, replaceTrack makes error
is there any other way for screen share?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a video track in order to achieve this. It will require renegotiation.

So add the screen track (not replace) to the connection and then create the offer again!

```
connection.addTrack(screenVideoTrack);
```

Check this for reference:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/onnegotiationneeded

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have already applied this resolution
But when create new offer after connect screen video track, that returns setRemoteDescription error.